# How to correct the error on missing valued TRUE/FALSE in ICdiffupper widesIII analysis

Tags: r

I am using the function wi of the package adehabitat to calculate selection 
ratios. I have the used and the available proportions for each "animal"  and i have an error that i don't know how to fix that.

In this case, it seems there is an error related to the upper limit of the confidence interval (`ICdiffupper`), but I cannot understand what is the problem with the data.

```
wi = widesIII(used, available, avknown=FALSE, alpha=0.05)
```

`used`=dataframe with proportion of used resources for each fire
`available`=dataframe with proportion of available resources for each fire
`avknown`=if the proportion is known (TRUE) or estimated (FALSE)
`alpha`=the level for the confidence intervals (95%)

This is the error message i got:

> Error in if (ICdiffupper[i, j] < 0) sig[i, j] <- "---" : 
>         missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed